# ValueError: Item wrong length 907 instead of 2000

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a csv file, that has 1000 columns. I need to read only the first 100 columns. I wrote this program for that:

```
import pandas as pd

list = []
for i in range (1, 100):
    list.append(i)
df = pd.read_csv('piwik_37_2016-07-08.csv',dtype = "unicode")
df = df[df.columns.isin(list)]
df.to_csv('abc.csv', index = False)
```

But I get error: ValueError: Item wrong length 907 instead of 2000. Can't figure out where I went wrong

Comment: don't name a variable `list`, `list` is a builtin. Can you share the first few lines of the csv? I suspect there is a quoting issue (though I also don't think the `dtype="unicode"` argument is correct, did you read that somewhere?).

Comment: The csv is huge. Won't be possible to share the entire row. The first few rows looks like this: `idSite idVisit visitIp visitorId actionDetails_0_type actionDetails_0_url actionDetails_0_pageTitle actionDetails_0_pageIdAction actionDetails_0_serverTimePretty actionDetails_0_pageId actionDetails_0_generationTime
37 131041565 67.173.37.156 f21c02d93e3dd612 action http://www.indianadunes.com/ Official Indiana Dunes Travel Guide 13972754 7/8/2016 23:52 527465863 1.38s`

Comment: That's not a csv, there's no commas. Is it space separated? (use `sep=" "`)

Comment: I copied it from excel that is formatted, its a csv.

Comment: @DigantaBharali CSV means *comma* separated values. It's common to use another separator and still name that CSV, but don't expect python to guess on its own if the file is *space* separated values.

Comment: @mcarton, it is a comma separated file. I formatted it in excel and then copied the output from there. That's why the commas are not reflected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of things strange about your code. For example, there is no reason to iterate over the range object and update a list just to get a list of numbers. Just use `list(range(1,100))`.

However, if you just need the first 100 columns in the csv, there is built-in functionality for what you are trying to do:

```
df = pd.read_csv('piwik_37_2016-07-08.csv',dtype = "unicode", usecols = list(range(100)))
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't realise that this would short circuit (skip to the next line) even if the csv was malformed. Nice!

Comment: Completely new to python. I tried your code. It says `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`

Comment: @DigantaBharali yes, because you overrode `list`. Don't do that.

Comment: @DigantaBharali Because you shadowed the built-in `list` function with an actual list object. Don't do that.

Comment: Sorry for asking a dumb question, I still don't see the remedy. I did `import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('piwik_37_2016-07-08.csv',dtype = "unicode", usecols = list(range(1,100))) df.to_csv('abc.csv', index = False)`. I recieve the list obect not callable error

Comment: @DigantaBharali Are you in the same interpreter session? You need to restart the interpreter. Also, if you use `list(range(1,100))` it will give you columns 2,3,...100. if you want columns 1,2,3...100 then you want to use `list(range(100))` because it accepts a list of the *indices*.

Comment: Working. I was running it in the same session. Can you guide me to some resources where I can get started with Python.

Comment: @junapa.arrivillaga, And if it is not too much to ask, could you guide me as to where my code went wrong?

Comment: @DigantaBharali --too many places the code isnt pythonic... Need  a good tutorial-- gave you one.

Answer (score 1):

Though its down voted, still answering as its a small correction in the code.

```
import pandas as pd

l = list(range(0,100))
df = pd.read_csv('piwik_37_2016-07-08.csv',dtype = "unicode")
df = df.loc[:,df.columns.isin(l)]
df.to_csv('abc.csv', index = False)
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer please ?

Comment: Hi @Toodoo, the difference is in using _loc_ convention from pandas. Selecting columns using boolean.

`df = df.loc[:,df.columns.isin(l)]`